# Setting using Content of CALayer's to Image.imageWithRenderingMode Does not work

Tags: ios, calayer

I am trying to set a "tinted" version UIImage to CALayer content property, but it resulted in the original image instead.

```
        var imageLayer = CALayer();
        imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
        imageLayer.contents = image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.ALwaysTemplate).CGImage;
```

Any idea how to use the AlwaysTemplate renderingMode version of the UIImage to the CALayer?

Comment: Afaik the `renderingMode` property is only evaluated by `UIImageView`, not by `CALayer`s directly. You'll either have to tint the image on your own, draw it by yourself or use `UIImageView`.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to achieve that effect via code? @fluidsonic

Comment: Found this after a quick search: https://github.com/raymondjavaxx/UIImage-RTTint - There are more libraries like this available online.